# Show multiple values for multiple keys in Java Hashmap

Tags: java, list, hashmap, set, java-8

```
public Map<String, List<String>> getContactMap() {
    Set<String> keys = contactMap.keySet(); //Get Key Set
    for(String key: keys){
        List<String> a=contactMap.get(key); //Get List for each Key
        a.forEach(System.out::println);     //Print the list
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have a Hashmap, with multiple values for a single key. I am using this code to print those values, but this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

I am only getting the last inserted value as output.

This is my addContact method:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> contactMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

@Override
public void addContact(String name, List<String> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    contactMap.put(name, list);
}
```

And this is my main():

```
List <String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("0321564988");
    list.add("7891268429");
    contacts.addContact("Name1",list);
    list.clear();
    list.add("1891219122");
    list.add("9495198929");
    contacts.addContact("Name2",list);
    list.clear();
    list.add("8949219912");
    contacts.addContact("Name3",list);
```

This is my desired output:

```
Name1   Phone1
        Phone2
        Phone3
Name2   Phone1
        Phone2
        .....
```

Comment: If you're only getting the last inserted value, perhaps you have a bug in your insertion code. Please show how you populate `contactMap`.

Comment: contactMap.put(name, list);

The list is okay, I checked it, during inserting..

Comment: `contactMap.put(name, list);` is exactly _not_ okay - it will replace the value each time. You need something like `contactMap.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value)`. Further, looping over keys and retrieving each value is an anti-pattern, use the `entrySet`,

Comment: Note that your printing code is a half-hearted mixture of imperative and functional programming. You can replace it with `contactMap.forEach((key, a) -> a.forEach(System.out::println));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have only last list included is because of your insert method:

```
List <String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("0321564988");
    list.add("7891268429");
    contacts.addContact("Name1",list);
    list.clear();
    list.add("1891219122");
    list.add("9495198929");
    contacts.addContact("Name2",list);
    list.clear();
    list.add("8949219912");
    contacts.addContact("Name3",list);
```

`Map` binds key- value pairs by referencing key (in your case `String` key) to object's memory address (in your case `List <String>`). Your map contains three different keys, but each one points to exactly the same object in memory. As a result, when you modify one `Map` entry, the change is valid for all keys. To correct your code you should initialize your list every time you want to add it:

```
List <String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("0321564988");
    list.add("7891268429");
    contacts.addContact("Name1",list);
List <String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("1891219122");
    list1.add("9495198929");
    contacts.addContact("Name2",list1);
List <String> list2= new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("8949219912");
    contacts.addContact("Name3",list2);
```

At the end it is worth pointing out, that "memory reference" is valid for elements derived from `Object` class. Basic types (i.e. `int, boolean, double`) are referenced by value, so for this sort of data your code would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
List <String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("0321564988");
list.add("7891268429");
contacts.addContact("Name1",list);
list.clear();
list.add("1891219122");
list.add("9495198929");
contacts.addContact("Name2",list);
list.clear();
list.add("8949219912");
contacts.addContact("Name3",list);
```

is wrong.

You are reusing the **same** `List`.

Look at a simple example:

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List <String> list2 = list;

list.add("0321564988");
list.add("7891268429");
list.clear();

list2.add("1891219122");
System.out.println(list2);
```

Output:

```
1891219122
```

Because, in Java, a `List` is a reference to a memory location containing that `List`. Java passes *references* (by value) so that when you pass the `List` to your `Map` you only pass a *reference* to that `List`. When you `clear` the `List` you clear the *memory location* and the reference in the `Map` still points to the same location.

I would suggest you change your method to:

```
public void addNumberForContact(String name, String number) {
    contactMap.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(number);
}
```

This way you abstract the creation of the `List` to a class that controls the `Map` so you don't have this problem.

Further, looping over a `Map` by key and then getting the value is an anti-pattern. A `Map` stores key -> value pairs together so you can use the `EntrySet`:

```
contactMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Okay!! I got the issue!! Thanks a ton!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to print the values of the *values*, you can do:

```
contactMap.entrySet().stream()
          .map(Entry::getValue)
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Also, if this is the only purpose of the method, it doesn't have to return anything, so change the return-type to `void` and remove the `return` statement.

Comment: Actually I wanted to do something like this---
Name1 Phone1
         Phone2
         Phone3

Name2 Phone1
         Phone2
         .....

Comment: Please provide some sample content and the desired output (in the question)

Comment: Shorter: `contactMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, the OP's code is fine (but rather ugly) and _should_ work if the `Map` is correct. I think the population of the `Map` is the issue.